Slow down dragging action in QListwidget scrollbar
I am using a list widget vertical scrollbar to have an alarm clock kind of thing, where I can set values of minutes and seconds.
The issue is, when I do the dragging, i.e, flick using touchpad, the scrolling becomes very fast, and it reaches 0 -30 at one scroll.
I tried to catch the slider released signal and slow it down, but the signal is not getting emitted.
All I want is to slow the scroller down when the user does a dragging action.
I want a similar behavior as in alarm clocks in phones, where if the user drags holding the number, it slows down gradually and fixes on a number. But, in my case, it goes straight from start to end without ever stopping.
mainwindow.h
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QListWidget>
#include <QScrollBar>
#include <QScroller>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    QListWidget *listWidget1;
    QListWidget *listWidget2;

    void createScroller();
    void handleScrollBar();
    void handleScrollBar2();
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H


this is my mainwindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QScroller>
#include <QScrollBar>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Create and set up ListWidget1
    listWidget1 = new QListWidget(this);
    listWidget2 = new QListWidget(this);

    QFont userScroller("DINCond-Bold", 17, QFont::Medium);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
        QListWidgetItem *item;
        if (i < 10)
            item = new QListWidgetItem("0" + QString::number(i));
        else
            item = new QListWidgetItem(QString::number(i));
        item->setFont(userScroller);
        listWidget1->addItem(item);
        item->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
    }

    // Append "00" for circular scrolling behavior
    QListWidgetItem *circularItem = new QListWidgetItem("00");
    circularItem->setFont(userScroller);
    circularItem->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
    listWidget1->addItem(circularItem);

    listWidget1->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    listWidget1->setStyleSheet("background:rgba(0,0,0,0.025);border-radius : 0px;border:0px;color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);");
    listWidget1->setSpacing(30);
    listWidget1->setFixedHeight(350);
    listWidget1->setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents, true);
    listWidget1->setAutoScroll(false);
    listWidget1->setDragEnabled(false);
    listWidget1->setAcceptDrops(false);
    listWidget1->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
    listWidget1->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::NoSelection);

    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        QListWidgetItem *item;
        if (i < 10)
            item = new QListWidgetItem("0" + QString::number(i));
        else
            item = new QListWidgetItem(QString::number(i));
        item->setFont(userScroller);
        item->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
        listWidget2->addItem(item);
    }

    listWidget2->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    listWidget2->setStyleSheet("background:rgba(0,0,0,0.025);border-radius : 0px;border:0px;color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);");
    listWidget2->setSpacing(30);
    listWidget2->setFixedHeight(350);
    listWidget2->setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents, true);
    listWidget2->setAutoScroll(false);
    listWidget2->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
    listWidget2->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::NoSelection);

    QScroller::grabGesture(listWidget1, QScroller::LeftMouseButtonGesture);
    QScroller::grabGesture(listWidget2, QScroller::LeftMouseButtonGesture);
    QScroller::grabGesture(listWidget1, QScroller::ScrollerGestureType::TouchGesture);
    QScroller::grabGesture(listWidget2, QScroller::ScrollerGestureType::TouchGesture);

    QHBoxLayout *listWidgetLayout1 = new QHBoxLayout();
    listWidgetLayout1->addWidget(listWidget1);

    QHBoxLayout *listWidgetLayout2 = new QHBoxLayout();
    listWidgetLayout2->addWidget(listWidget2);

    QHBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
    mainLayout->addLayout(listWidgetLayout1);
    mainLayout->addLayout(listWidgetLayout2);

    QWidget *centralWidget = new QWidget(this);
    centralWidget->setLayout(mainLayout);
    setCentralWidget(centralWidget);

    // Initialize scrollers
    createScroller();
    handleScrollBar();
    handleScrollBar2();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::createScroller()
{
    QScroller *scroller1 = QScroller::scroller(listWidget1->viewport());
    QScroller *scroller2 = QScroller::scroller(listWidget2->viewport());

    if (scroller1) {
        QScrollerProperties scrollerProps = scroller1->scrollerProperties();
        scrollerProps.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::VerticalOvershootPolicy, QScrollerProperties::OvershootAlwaysOff);
        scrollerProps.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::DecelerationFactor, 10);
        scrollerProps.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::MaximumVelocity, 0.0005);
        //scrollerProps.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::ScrollingCurve, QEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::Linear));
        scrollerProps.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::DragVelocitySmoothingFactor, 1);
        scrollerProps.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::OvershootDragResistanceFactor, 0);
        scrollerProps.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::OvershootScrollTime, 0);
        scrollerProps.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::OvershootScrollDistanceFactor, 0.1);
        scrollerProps.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::SnapTime, 0.0006);
        scrollerProps.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::SnapPositionRatio, 0.5);
        scrollerProps.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::MaximumClickThroughVelocity, 0.01);
        scrollerProps.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::MinimumVelocity, 0);
        scrollerProps.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::MaximumVelocity, 0);
        scroller1->setScrollerProperties(scrollerProps);
    }

    if (scroller2) {
        QScrollerProperties scrollerProps = scroller2->scrollerProperties();
        scrollerProps.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::VerticalOvershootPolicy, QScrollerProperties::OvershootAlwaysOff);
        scrollerProps.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::DecelerationFactor, 10);
        scrollerProps.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::MaximumVelocity, 0.0005);
        //scrollerProps.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::ScrollingCurve, QEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::Linear));
        scrollerProps.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::DragVelocitySmoothingFactor, 1);
        scrollerProps.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::OvershootDragResistanceFactor, 0);
        scrollerProps.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::OvershootScrollTime, 0);
        scrollerProps.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::OvershootScrollDistanceFactor, 0.1);
        scrollerProps.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::SnapTime, 0.0006);
        scrollerProps.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::SnapPositionRatio, 0.5);
        scrollerProps.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::MaximumClickThroughVelocity, 0.01);
        scrollerProps.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::MinimumVelocity, 0);
        scrollerProps.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::MaximumVelocity, 0);
        scroller2->setScrollerProperties(scrollerProps);
    }
}

void MainWindow::handleScrollBar()
{
    int mins = listWidget1->verticalScrollBar()->value();
    int secs = listWidget2->verticalScrollBar()->value();

    QString minsStr = (mins < 10) ? "0" + QString::number(mins) : QString::number(mins);
    QString secsStr = (secs < 10) ? "0" + QString::number(secs) : QString::number(secs);
}

void MainWindow::handleScrollBar2()
{
    int scrollbarValue = listWidget2->verticalScrollBar()->value();
    int mins = listWidget1->verticalScrollBar()->value() + 1;
    int secs = scrollbarValue + 1;

    QString minsStr = (mins < 10) ? "0" + QString::number(mins) : QString::number(mins);
    QString secsStr = (secs < 10) ? "0" + QString::number(secs) : QString::number(secs);
QString vtime = minsStr  + secsStr ;

    qDebug() << "Updated time: " << vtime;
}



Please provide a [mre], a single main.cpp that we could copy-paste, build, and run directly to see/test the issue you're describing.

@A.R.M I have edited my question to include a working mainwindow.cpp. If you use it in qt you will see that it scrolls down very fast from 0-30 in one go when we drag whereas in phone when we press and drag it slows down after sometime and gets to a number
Also i can't use scrollbypixel as the values in scrollbar are important to me as the combined values of scrollbar 1 and 2 will be used to set a countdown timer

Thanks for the edit, it's a bit clearer now. However, that is not what I asked for (read the link). Someone could make a [mre] out of the code you shared, but they will have to spend a lot more effort than what they should be spending. Everything not necessary to reproducing the problem should not be there. Take this question as an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78986521/clear-focus-from-qtablewidget-once-tab-key-navigation-reaches-the-last-item/78987444#78987444

@A.R.M thanks for pointing it out. But i tried to include the things i thought would make it easier to reproduce and understand my problem of the dragging event. I am still new to this and will try to make a minimal reproducible ex for this. But would be interested to know if the edit i did helped to understand my issue?

Personally, I already got the general idea of your problem, and an expert could probably figure out what's wrong already. But the goal of Stack Overflow is to be helpful for everyone visiting it. Which is why it requires the simplest form of your code to reproduce the issue, the simpler it is, the more people it will help in the future. It's not easy to make a [mre], but that's one of the skills we should develop in this field. It will take time though.

I should also reassert that you explain why you wrote the code that way, so that we get an idea on how you're currently approaching the problem. Thank you for your cooperation, it's much appreciated. Good luck.

@A.R.M Thanks for helping me out to understand the importance of the minimum reproducible example. I am trying to make one but what my intention was that if somebody runs my example they should be able to reproduce the issue.

Now my problem statement was to design a timer i would say where user can scroll on one scrollbar to select minutes and the other scrollbar to select seconds and based on both the values selected by used the timer should start decrementing.
I have used listwidgets and scrollby value as i should get the values selected by the user to start the timer. Scrollby pixel does make the scrolling slow but i don't get the exact values. I have tried to set the properties like deceleration factor to low values such that the scrollbar doesn't go from 0 to end value at one go which is inconvenient for user

"my intention was that if somebody runs my example they should be able to reproduce the issue.", well, that's the point, to run your example, we need it simplified. The current code needs to be modified, in order for us to be able to run it. The best thing about making a minimal example is that you might even solve the problem yourself, because the simpler it gets, the easier it becomes to spot where you went wrong. I haven't asked a question in ages because I learned how to make minimal reproducible examples. And you probably have more experience than I do!

I've never played around enough with QScroller, so I'm not 100% sure this is the problem, but you're calling grabGesture() twice on each widget, and the documentation explicitly says that "Only one scroll gesture can be active on a single object at the same time. If you call this function twice on the same object, it will ungrab the existing gesture before grabbing the new one."

Thanks for the advice. I did have a look at the documentation and removed one which was not relevant, but it didn't solve my issue @musicamante
